How to plot a map based on actual latitude and longitude?
I have a region divided by longitude and latitude. I know that the distance of 1 degree of latitude is 111,320m, and the distance of 1 degree of longitude varies with the latitude. The size of my grid is 25m×25m, and the grid shown in the figure (a total of 600 grids) is too large (see the figure below), which is not realistic.

My code is as below：
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
color_breaks <- c(0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0)
colors <- c("#E31A1C", "#FF7F00", "#FDBF6F", "#E9E4A6", "#A4D4A9", "#B2DF8A", "#33A02C", "#1F78B4")

p1 <- ggplot(merged_data, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, z = median_mafruit)) +
  labs(
    title = "Data1",
    subtitle = "10 years",
    x = "Longitude (°)",
    y = "Latitude (°)",
    fill = expression("Amount")
  ) +
  theme_minimal()

p1<-p1 +
  stat_summary_2d(
    aes(fill = after_stat(
      cut(
        value,
        breaks = c(0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0),
        include.lowest = TRUE,
        right = FALSE
      )
    )),
    bins = 30,
    show.legend = TRUE
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = colors,
    drop = FALSE,
    guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12, face = "italic"),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
    legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.5, "cm"),
    legend.spacing.y = unit(0.5, "cm")
  )
p1

Part of my dataset is shown below:
structure(list(Order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), latitude = c(43.2143, 43.3697, 
43.3909, 43.3926, 43.3961, 43.3978, 43.066, 43.2215, 43.368, 
43.435, 43.4434, 43.4623, 43.4895, 43.4856, 43.3738, 43.4761, 
43.5102, 43.5118, 43.5062, 43.4933), longitude = c(-4.479, -4.4804, 
-4.4606, -4.4484, -4.4241, -4.412, -4.1046, -4.1049, -4.1031, 
-4.0818, -4.021, -3.9502, -3.8184, -3.7798, -3.7279, -3.7147, 
-3.5971, -3.5849, -3.5585, -3.5177), median_mafruit = c(2.73, 
1.095, 1.115, 2.73, 0.527, 0.527, 0.962, 1.039, 1.039, 2.73, 
2.73, 2.73, 2.73, 2.73, 0.544, 2.73, 2.73, 2.73, 0.478, 2.73)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Order = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), latitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), longitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), median_mafruit = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

I want to keep appropriate gaps between grids, and the lengths of the horizontal and vertical coordinates of the image should be more in line with the actual proportion (currently 2 latitudes correspond to 5 longitudes, which is not practical).

If the approximation is good enough for your purpose, you can set an aspect ratio of 1:1 like ggplot(...) + ... + coord_fixed().

This problem seems better suited to one of the Geographical Information Systems packages R has available.  If you plot your data using a geographical package, the coordinate reference system and/or projection deals with precisely this problem.  Would you be open to such a solution?

Yes. Could you please recommend one geographical package to me? @Sean McKenzie

Looks like @L Tyrone beat me to the punch.  They recommended the two packages I would have recommended: sf for vector data (i.e, points, lines, polygons) and terra for raster data (i.e., grids of continuous values across landscapes like aerial imagery or digital elevation models.  I would also recommend looking into the tmap of leaflet packages if you want your graphics to appear as a map rather than a graph.  Both packages accept objects from both sf and terra.  There are great tutorials for all four packages from the r-spatial group: https://r-spatial.org/book/

You can use coord_sf(), which among other things interprets coordinates relative to a geographic or projected coordinate system. In your example, I have assumed your coordinates are WGS84/EPSG:4326. If they are in a different coordinate system, you can look up the relevant EPSG code online, then replace 4326 with the correct code.
If you intend to use ggplot2 to plot spatial data in the future, I recommend you explore the sf and terra packages. For sf objects, you can use geom_sf(), which 'intuitively' handles coordinates etc. For SpatRaster objects, you will need the tidyterra package to use geom_spatraster().
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

p1 <- ggplot(merged_data, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, z = median_mafruit)) +
  labs(
    title = "Data1",
    subtitle = "10 years",
    x = "Longitude (°)",
    y = "Latitude (°)",
    fill = expression("Amount")
  ) +
  theme_minimal()

p1 <- p1 +
  stat_summary_2d(
    aes(fill = after_stat(
      cut(
        value,
        breaks = c(0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0),
        include.lowest = TRUE,
        right = FALSE
      )
    )),
    bins = 30,
    show.legend = TRUE
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = colors,
    drop = FALSE,
    guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)
  ) +
  coord_sf(datum = 4326
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12, face = "italic"),
    legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
    legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm"),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.5, "cm"),
    legend.spacing.y = unit(0.5, "cm")
  )
p1


